HMAC signing with Named Credentials and OAuth
Context

I'm setting up an External Data Source pointing to an OData API.
I've setup a Named Credential and an External Credential for it.
The External Credential is configured to use OAuth2.0 (JWT Bearer flow)
with the Identity Provider URL pointing at my own API to provide an
access token which is then present in all future calls under the
Authorization header.

All of this so far is working well, back and forth between Salesforce, my identity provider and my OData API all authentication works as expected.
Goal
I want to include a request integrity check in this flow.
My intention was to add a custom header to my External Credential that contained an HMAC signature of my request (body//query). This way I could, as part of authenticating Salesforce in my API, check that the request hasn't been tampered with.
This would be targeting MITM (man in the middle) attacks stopping people from capturing my request and replaying it with modifications to an OData Query to get data they shouldn't be getting.
Problem
I can't for the life of me find enough documentation on what "scoped" data I have available within a custom header. In the main documentation regarding custom headers in named credentials, there's some merge fields that are mentioned to be used in Basic auth or API Key auth. Most of them refer to using a Custom authentication method in the External Credential, but not available otherwise.
I can't find what merge fields I have outside of $Credential and $User, and in those I don't really know what properties are available to me.
The feeling I have is that I don't have a $Request.Body or $Request.Query, that I can use. But the documentation is so sparse I could be wrong.
Questions

Is it possible for me to reference Request scoped information (query string, body) within a custom header?
Is there a piece of documentation that clearly highlights all available merge fields within an External Credential?
Is there a way of producing a random GUID (or number even) inside a custom header? I could leverage this to achieve a similar integrity check.
Any ideas on a completely different tactic to achieve the same integrity check?

Thank you in advance :)

This would be targeting MITM (man in the middle) attacks - what, by breaking TLS protocol?

@identigral, thank you for your comment. I'm not sure how adding an extra header with an HMAC signature of the body and query breaks TLS protocol. TLS encrypts the entire request including the headers. Can you expand further on it, or link me to some article talking about it?

We meant that your desire to mitigate the MITM risk is a XY Problem. The MITM attacker would have to eavesdrop on the connection, thus successfully breaking TLS protocol, a very tall order.  Consult oAuth BCP for real risks and countermeasures.
